# Target property type in decorators

Tags: typescript, decorator

Seems to me kinda *undertyped* compared to other sometimes really complex types all over TypeScript universe to have type `Function` for `target` property in decorator functions. The only example with a strict type is stated in [Class Decorators](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md#class-decorators) section. I understand there are no classes in JS per se, but as TypeScript operates only in design and build time, it understands classes a different way so why there are no stronger types for `target` decorator parameter in the handbook?

```js
function sealed(constructor: Function)
```

vs

```js
function classDecorator<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T)
```

or simply

```js
function classDecorator(constructor:{new(...args:any[]):{}})
```